# How to make a "read more" link in widget wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress. I want to create "read more" link to detailed article, because somtimes it is too long. How can I do it? Help me please.

My pic:

[image: screenshot]

My code: our_team.php

```
<?php
            echo '<section class="our-team" id="team">';

                echo '<div class="container">';

                    echo '<div class="section-header">';

                        $zerif_ourteam_title = get_theme_mod('zerif_ourteam_title',__('YOUR TEAM','zerif-lite'));

                        if( !empty($zerif_ourteam_title) ):
                            echo '<h2 class="dark-text">'.$zerif_ourteam_title.'</h2>';
                        endif;

                        $zerif_ourteam_subtitle = get_theme_mod('zerif_ourteam_subtitle',__('Prove that you have real people working for you, with some nice looking profile pictures and links to social media.','zerif-lite'));

                        if( !empty($zerif_ourteam_subtitle) ):

                            echo '<div class="section-legend">'.$zerif_ourteam_subtitle.'</div>';

                        endif;

                    echo '</div>';

                    if(is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-ourteam' )):
                        echo '<div class="row" data-scrollreveal="enter left after 0s over 0.1s">';
                            dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-ourteam' );
                        echo '</div> ';
                    else:
                        echo '<div class="row" data-scrollreveal="enter left after 0s over 0.1s">';
                        the_widget( 'zerif_team_widget','name=ASHLEY SIMMONS&position=Project Manager&description=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dapibus, eros at accumsan auctor, felis eros condimentum quam, non porttitor est urna vel neque&fb_link=#&tw_link=#&bh_link=#&db_link=#&ln_link=#&image_uri='.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/team1.png', array('before_widget' => '', 'after_widget' => '') );
                        the_widget( 'zerif_team_widget','name=TIMOTHY SPRAY&position=Art Director&description=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dapibus, eros at accumsan auctor, felis eros condimentum quam, non porttitor est urna vel neque&fb_link=#&tw_link=#&bh_link=#&db_link=#&ln_link=#&image_uri='.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/team2.png', array('before_widget' => '', 'after_widget' => '') );
                        the_widget( 'zerif_team_widget','name=TONYA GARCIA&position=Account Manager&description=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dapibus, eros at accumsan auctor, felis eros condimentum quam, non porttitor est urna vel neque&fb_link=#&tw_link=#&bh_link=#&db_link=#&ln_link=#&image_uri='.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/team3.png', array('before_widget' => '', 'after_widget' => '') );
                        the_widget( 'zerif_team_widget','name=JASON LANE&position=Business Development&description=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dapibus, eros at accumsan auctor, felis eros condimentum quam, non porttitor est urna vel neque&fb_link=#&tw_link=#&bh_link=#&db_link=#&ln_link=#&image_uri='.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/team4.png', array('before_widget' => '', 'after_widget' => '') );
                        echo '</div>';
                    endif;

                echo '</div>';

            echo '</section>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, **prepare landing page**.

You want to create "read more" link, and it must lead somewhere. If you already have that "somewhere", skip this step.

Start by creating usual Wordpress page. Name it "Team", "About Us" or something like that. Obviously, that page should contain some information about each team member. Wrap info about every person in div with unique id (I would use some variation of name for that):

```
<div id="ashley">
    ... About Ashley HTML
</div>
```

**Remember address of page** (it is displayed below Title field).

Then, **modify widgets**.

On place you have captured in your screenshot, you can click these arrows facing down to modify information about each person on main page. Most of fields don't allow HTML in content, but *Position* and *Description* are exceptions<sup>[1]</sup>. You can include your link as long as you are capable of writing HTML by hand.

Just follow this template:

```
<a href="[address of page]#[id of person]">Read more</a>
```

Where:

- `[address of page]` is address of page you have created in first step (`/team/`, `/about-us/` or something)
- `[id of person]` is content of `id` attribute of div that is wrapping info about particular person (`ashley` etc.)
- Don't forget number sign (`#`) between!

This is how widget content can look like:

[image: Sample widget with HTML]

Finally, **review description content**.

You said that description is "sometimes too long". The problem is that you have only very limited control over how your users will see your page. Text that is acceptable length for you might end up too long on mobile device, due to limited viewport width.

I would suggest that you resort to short description on main page and provide longer text on separate page. This way you will also ensure that every team member has "Read more" link on main page and separate page doesn't miss anyone.

One **huge drawback** of this method is that it is all manual. It is your responsibility to keep both pages in sync. This is especially important if you ever decide to change team composition or any team member change name. You must also ensure that the same image is used in both places.

This is necessary, because this theme uses widgets to generate that data on main page, and widgets are things that display some content wherever they were placed. There is no **page** associated with widget so, by default, there is nowhere you could send your users.

Of course it is possible to generate "About" page dynamically, or to modify main page to display something else than widgets, but this probably falls outside of scope of simple answer on this site.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Content of these fields is run through [`wp_filter_post_kses`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_post_kses) before being displayed. That function strips all tags that are not present in `$allowedposttags` global array. That array can be overridden by `CUSTOM_TAGS` constant and **plugins are allowed to modify it**.